# Alternative to LAG funtion for service desk query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have a query for my service desk , when i run it i get an error 'LAG' is not a recognized built in function name. I know the reason of this error because lag is introduced from SQL Server 2012 on ward. however my service desk db is SQL Server 2008. Is their any alternative to LAG function for the below query.

enter code here

```
SELECT woh.workorderid 'Request ID', 
sd.Statusname 'Status',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dateadd(s,datediff(s,getutcdate(),getdate())+((LAG(woh.operationtime) OVER (ORDER BY woh.historyid))/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 100) AS "Previous Date",
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dateadd(s,datediff(s,getutcdate(),getdate())+(woh.operationtime/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 100) AS "Current Date",
DATEDIFF(minute, dateadd(s,datediff(s,getutcdate(),getdate())+((LAG(woh.operationtime) OVER (ORDER BY woh.historyid)) /1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'), dateadd(s,datediff(s,getutcdate(),getdate())+(woh.operationtime/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00')) as "Minutes taken to Respond" 
FROM workorderhistory woh
LEFT JOIN workorderhistorydiff wohd ON wohd.Historyid=woh.Historyid 
LEFT JOIN Statusdefinition sd ON sd.Statusid=CAST(wohd.Current_value AS INT) 
LEFT JOIN workorder wo ON wo.workorderid = woh.workorderid
WHERE (((woh.Operation='CREATE' AND wohd.Columnname IS NULL) OR woh.Operation='RESOLVED' OR woh.Operation='CLOSE') OR (woh.Operation='UPDATE' AND wohd.Columnname='STATUSID'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Left Join` and `Row_Number` window function

```
;WITH cteworkorderhistory
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY historyid) AS Rn
         FROM   workorderhistory)
SELECT woh.workorderid                                                                                                                                                                                                                    'Request ID',
       sd.Statusname                                                                                                                                                                                                                      'Status',
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Dateadd(s, Datediff(s, Getutcdate(), Getdate()) + ( ( b.operationtime ) / 1000 ), '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 100)                                                                                                AS "Previous Date",
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Dateadd(s, Datediff(s, Getutcdate(), Getdate()) + ( woh.operationtime / 1000 ), '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 100)                                                                                                  AS "Current Date",
       Datediff(minute, Dateadd(s, Datediff(s, Getutcdate(), Getdate()) + ( ( b.operationtime ) / 1000 ), '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), Dateadd(s, Datediff(s, Getutcdate(), Getdate()) + ( woh.operationtime / 1000 ), '1970-01-01 00:00:00')) AS "Minutes taken to Respond"
FROM   cteworkorderhistory woh
       LEFT JOIN cteworkorderhistory b
              ON b.Rn = woh.Rn - 1
       LEFT JOIN workorderhistorydiff wohd
              ON wohd.Historyid = woh.Historyid
       LEFT JOIN Statusdefinition sd
              ON sd.Statusid = Cast(wohd.Current_value AS INT)
       LEFT JOIN workorder wo
              ON wo.workorderid = woh.workorderid
WHERE  ( ( ( woh.Operation = 'CREATE'
             AND wohd.Columnname IS NULL )
            OR woh.Operation = 'RESOLVED'
            OR woh.Operation = 'CLOSE' )
          OR ( woh.Operation = 'UPDATE'
               AND wohd.Columnname = 'STATUSID' ) )
```

Comment: Getting error " The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator." for the above code

Comment: @Biswa I don't know the datatypes of your columns so I cannot really comment on the same.. My guess is one of the column in `where` clause is `Ntext` and you are comparing with `=` operator so the error